# What's GCC for #pragma code_seg?

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

In MSVC, you can rename the .text section in a compiled file with

```
#pragma code_seg(".text.but_not_really")
```

At link time, it will be properly merged with the rest of the .text sections. Is there an equivalent in GCC 4.8, please?

Comment: That's on the function basis. How about on the source file basis?